# why does std::thread throws an error when it's asked to run an overloaded function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

below is the code i am running , it throws an error in the lines where i am passing overloaded function 'myfunc' in thread object t1 and t2
(also identified with a comment)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

    void  myfunc(int x)
        {
            cout << x << endl;
        }

    void  myfunc(int  x,int y)
    
    {
        
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }

    int main()
    {
    
        thread t1(myfunc,1);//error here
        thread t2(myfunc, 1,2);//error here
        
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        return 0;
    }
```

The error statement:

**Error 1:**
*Error (active) E0289   no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list arguments type are: (unknown-type,int)*

**Error 2:**
*Error (active) E0289   no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list arguments type are: (unknown-type,int,int)*

Comment: I'll bet that there's more error output, including something about ambiguous functions. The compiler doesn't know which overload should be used when you pass them to the thread constructor.

Comment: The compiler doesn't understand the semantics of `std::thread`, and doesn't know that the class will eventually internally call the first parameter passing in the rest. So it has no way to choose the correct overload. Either give these two functions different names, or else you'd have to cast, as in `std::thread t1(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(myfunc), 1);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have overloaded functions that you pass as arguments, you need to help the compiler.

Possible solution:

```
using f1 = void(*)(int);
using f2 = void(*)(int, int);

thread t1(static_cast<f1>(myfunc), 1);
thread t2(static_cast<f2>(myfunc), 1, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can ask for an overload resolution at a later moment by wrapping `myfunc` into a lambda:

```
std::thread t1([](auto... args) { myfunc(args...); }, 1);
std::thread t2([](auto... args) { myfunc(args...); }, 1, 2);
```